# Laravel Nova: Generate Model-Values without field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova

Is there an option to generate Model-Values by not having a form input at the nova backend?

For example after every store / update I would like to update the created_by value with the current authenticated user.

**Exampl:e**

```
$model->created_by = aut()->user()->id
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your model, you can add a boot() method which will allow you to manage `saving` event

Available events are `creating, created, updating, updated, saving,  saved, deleting, deleted, restoring, restored`

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::saving(function($model){
        $model->created_by = auth()->user()->id;
    });
}
```

In that way every time you create/update model created_by attribute will be updated..

Comment: Perfect, i thought there is an way in nova but this seems pretty clear.